# How can I calculate these normal distribution exercises

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I got to calculate the value for the variable $c$ when they give me this intervals but I don't know how to interpret the inequations.

a) $P(-c \le z \le c) = .668$.

b) $P(c \le |z|) = .016$.

Comment: What are $n$ and $p$?

Comment: Are you using **tables** of the normal distribution, or software?

Comment: I got to use the tables at last, I just would like to clear what is the right value I got to look for on the table to know c

Comment: Binomial distribution isn't defined on negative values.

Comment: Ok. any other parameters are known, like mean..? Can we state then, that it is about a **normal** distribution instead of binomial?

Comment: You are right I just was wrong on the question title. It's about normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. We have a *probability variable* $z$: some random thing happens, and then $z$ gets a value, assumed as a real number.

If this 'random thing' occurs according to a given distribution, then the corresponding *distribution function* is defined as:
$$F(t):=P(z<t)$$
If the distribution is *continuous*, then all single points have zero probability, so $F(t)=P(z\le t)$. And, (assumed that $z$ has value with $1$ probability:) we also have $P(z>t) = 1-P(z\le t)$.

In your case, if you have given a continuous distriution by $F$, then
$$\text{a) }\ P(-c\le z\le c) = F(c)-F(-c)$$
$$\text{b) }\ P(c\le|z|) = P((z\ge c)\lor(z\le -c))=1-F(c) + F(-c) $$

Now, if it happens to be the **standard normal** distribution (that is, in a sense a *limit* of binomial distributions), then $F=\Phi$ and you can also use its symmetry: $\Phi(-c) = 1-\Phi(c)$.